# How does one target specific object of a gui for an event flow?

Tags: javascript, html, events, flash

I'm working on a javascript framework for creating simple animations on an html canvas with nested sprites using a basic composite pattern.

I've been modeling my work on Clutter and Flash (very similar structure). A "Stage" holds all of the items on screen, which are "DisplayObjects". These can be aggregated in a "DisplayObjectContainer", which inherits from "DisplayObject". The "Stage" itself is also a "DisplayObjectContainer". All of these inherit from an "EventDispatcher".

I've spent the better part of the last few days reading about the event flow of these systems and searching for examples in various open source projects.

From what I understand, when an event is dispatched, it should follow a certain propagation path: it flows from the stage, into the display object hierarchy (the "capture" phase) until it reaches the "target" of that event, and then "bubbles" back up the display hierarchy. If this isn't clear enough, the images located here should help explain:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e4f.html

http://docs.clutter-project.org/docs/clutter/1.4/event-flow.png

There is an aspect of this that I'm failing to understand, and I can't tell if it's just me or if this is as unclear as I think it is:

Suppose I'm dealing with clicks. I click on the display and use the browser's native event handling to retrieve the x/y coordinates of the click, and then send that down the display hierarchy to determine which object I've clicked.

Until now, this WAS the "capture" phase in my code. But this is completely at odds with the documentation which says the target should already be attached to the event by the time it enters the event flow.

Am I really supposed to traverse my graph of display items twice?

Any advice or expertise on the issue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing this as a learning experience? there are lots of existing frameworks out there like easleJS

Comment: partially a learning experience (event driven programming has always been a bit fuzzy to me, and understanding the underlying behaviors would be incredibly useful), mostly because i'd like to keep it incredibly lightweight for a separate project that would use it.

Comment: also, thanks, i will make use of the easelJS docs

Comment: Second the suggestion you look at easel since it was specifically designed (by a former Flash developer) to provide Flash display list like functionality for canvas development.

Comment: So the answer to the actual question (in terms of EaselJS's implementation) is that the target changes according to the level of event propagation - for each step in the event capture and bubble phases, the target is always the current DisplayObjectContainer rather than the leaf DisplayObject. I was so far off in my understanding of this; I thought the target was, for some reason, always supposed to be the leaf node in the display hierarchy. Perhaps the documentation elsewhere was confusing me. It's nice to see an actual, open implementation without having to reverse engineer APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question! Yes, I believe you would need to traverse your `DisplayList` first to calculate the event `target` before beginning the `capture` phase of your event-flow. Never having designed an event system, I'm not completely sure about this, but perhaps when you calculate the `target` object you could cache the hierarchical route and use that as the basis of your event-flow rather than traversing the `DisplayList` again.

The bit that you're unclear on, I think, is more obvious if you consider it in terms of implementation rather than in the abstract of designing an event system (and the terminology of existing event systems). Imagine, a widget consisting of a parent object, and a number of child items which need to react to mouse clicks. You might decide you want to listen for events on the parent object only, but react according to the target object from which the event originated. In `ActionScript`, if you're using the capture phase of the event-flow, your handler would fire before the target of the event is reached but, in this case, the target is an essential property of the event object.

As suggested in the comments, it might be worth looking at the [source code](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/src/easeljs/) for [easeljs](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS) since it claims to provide an API "that is familiar to Flash developers". However, note that easeljs does not currently support a full-featured event flow for performance reasons (see [here](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/140)).

My two pennies; event-flow is tricky enough to understand (let alone design) and implementing a full-featured event system may be at odds with your goal of creating a light-weight library. I would suggest you keep it simple at this stage and only add features such as event `bubbling` if you find you need them.

Comment: Okay, so it _was_ just me :) I do certainly get caught up in semantics sometimes. Although, this discussion has certainly solidified my understanding of event handling in general. Thanks!